# How can I use navigationRailView together with the Navigation library? (Have a standard switching of fragments, display of all icons)

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, material-components-android, android-navigationview

Rail menu with nav_graph added. All the icons are switched, but the fragments do not change.

P.S I know about the option with Selected, but I want everything to work cleanly and with the Navigation library

My code is now:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(
            R.id.nav_host_container
        ) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        // Setup navigationRailView
        val navigationRailView = findViewById<NavigationRailView>(R.id.navigation_rail)
        navigationRailView.setupWithNavController(navController)


    }


}
```

Android Studio offers:

`// private fun NavigationRailView.setupWithNavController(navController: NavController) {}`